# Help approaching finding the roots of $((z-1)^{20}-2)((z+2)^{10}+1024) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Looking for a good way to start finding the roots of this polynomial. I tried converting to polar and using Euler's formula but went terrible wrong somewhere. Thanks for helping a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

If $$((z-1)^{20}-2)((z+2)^{10}+1024)=0$$

Then,

$((z-1)^{20}-2)=0$ or $((z+2)^{10}+1024)=0$

Are you able to solve the two equations?

Answer (score 1):

Your polynomial is the product of two polynomials, and that product should evaluate to $0$. That means that one of the factors must be $0$. Then either $(z-1)^{20} = 2$ or $(z+2)^{10} = -1024$. Setting $x = z-1$ and $y = z+2$ you're tasked with finding all solutions to $x^{20} = 2$ and $y^{10} = -1024$. This is not difficult to do by, as you said, converting to polar form. Once you've found the solutions in terms of $x$ and $y$, you need to transform back into $z$.

Comment: [this may be useful](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZuK7H6ezOAhWCQyYKHROwBo0QFgggMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRoot_of_unity&usg=AFQjCNGATmxQjHcJTwTDow_GZRo6pzB3ug)

Comment: $(z+2)^{10}=-1024$, not $1024$.